# Does changing the version of R require changing in Rstudio version too?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R3.3.2 and wondering if I upgrade my R version to 3.5.3, Should I change the Rstudio_0.99.903 version to any other version that fits the new R version?

Comment: Changing the R version does not imply changing RStudio. R is the programming language, while RStudio is the IDE. However, it always good to update everything to the last stable version :)

Comment: ...and that RStudio version is also very old; there have been many, many new features and bug fixes added to the most recent version.

Comment: many thanks. I install R3.5.3 with the previous version of Rstudio and then update Rstudio too.